# How to update a specific cell on a PrimeFaces dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

In my `dataTable` I am linking each article with a specific task.

On the click of a `commandButton` a list of tasks shows up, so I want on the select of a task, update a specific cell in the `dataTable` (`outputText` with `id="columnTache"`) without updating the rest of my `dataTable`.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myController.articleList}" 
             id="tabArticle"                            
             var="article"  
             rowKey="#{article.id}"  >
    <p:column headerText="quantite" >
        <pe:inputNumber value="#{article.quantite}" />
    </p:column>                            
    <p:column headerText="taches" >     
        <h:outputText value="#{article.tache.libelleTache}" id="columnTache" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="taches"  >
        <p:commandButton  oncomplete="PF('dialogTasks').show();" update=":formSelectAffecterTache">
            <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{myController.setArticle(article)}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="#{bundleTech.lbl_taches}" widgetVar="dialogTasks" >     
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" >
        <h:form id="formSelectAffecterTache">
            <ui:include src="/pages/listTacheSelect.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="bean" value="#{myController}" />
                <ui:param name="action" value="affecterTache" /> 
            </ui:include>               
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>        
</p:dialog>
```

The update of my `dataTable` is in the managed bean:

```
public void affecterTache() {
    article.setTache(selectedSingleTache);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:tabArticle");           
}
```

Comment: Your Datatable is updating entirely because of your `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:tabArticle");`.

Comment: exactly @hamza-don what do i have to edit so that it updates just the cell with the id columnTache

Comment: Why don't you use the Datatable's [Cell Edit](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dataTable` is a naming container, so components within it will be prepended with the `dataTable`'s `id`. Also, each iteration of data presented in the table (each row) will have effect of the generated `id`s. Since a form is also a naming container, your `outputText` component `id`s will be generated as `formId:tabArticle:0:columnTache` in the first row, `formId:tabArticle:0:columnTache` in the second row, etc.

If you would set an `id` on your `commandButton` you will get `formId:tabArticle:0:myButton`, `formId:tabArticle:1:myButton` etc. You can use this `id` in your click handler to create the corresponding `inputText` `clientId`. But, since you pass `article` to a method, you are not able to check which button was clicked. So first of all change the click listeners method to:

```
public void useArticle(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
}
```

Now, you know which button was clicked (`event.getComponent()`), but you need your `article` as well. You can set that as an attribute to your button in XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton id="myButton"
                 oncomplete="PF('dialogTasks').show();" 
                 update=":formSelectAffecterTache">
    <p:ajax event="click"
            listener="#{myController.useArticle}" />
    <f:attribute name="article"
                 value="#{article}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This attribute can be read in your listener:

```
Article article = (Article) component.getAttributes().get("article");
```

Now, for updating the `inputText`, simply use the button's `clientId`:

```
String update = component.getClientId().replace(":myButton", ":columnTache");
```

Store it in your bean, and when you are ready to do so, update:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(update);
```

See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)
- [Send additional parameter to Ajax event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143601/send-additional-parameter-to-ajax-event-listener)