# How can I render another attribute from a p:dataTable of the same row (JSF)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am working with JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6.0. I have a `p:dataTable` with different `p:column`s, and each column has many rows. I would like that, whenever `column1` `input` changes, `column2` `input`, in the same row, updates, however, it is not working; it doesn't render.

This is my xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.objectsList}" var="object">
  <p:column headerText="column1">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <ui:repeat value="#{object.subObjects}" var="object2">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <c:set var="object3" value="#{object2.subObjects}"/>
              <h:inputText id="value1#{myBean.toString(object3)}" value="#{object3.value1}">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.doSomething}"
                        execute="@this" render="@this"/>
              </h:inputText>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="column2">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <ui:repeat value="#{object.subObjects}" var="object2">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <c:set var="object3" value="#{object2.subObjects}"/>
              <h:inputText value="#{object3.value2}" disabled="disabled">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.doSomething2}"
                        execute="@this" render="value1#{myBean.toString(object3)}"/>
              </h:inputText>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Each `object` has many `objects` as a `List`.

Comment: two upvotes in 9 views for this question? Do you have co-workers that upvoted it?

Comment: Related (or even duplicate): [How to update a specific cell on a PrimeFaces dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990292/how-to-update-a-specific-cell-on-a-primefaces-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

In `f:ajax` tag of the first column (`column1`), you have given `@this` as value for the attribute `render`.
Instead, please try giving id of the component `column2` or id of the `p:dataTable`itself.